# A Query of certain students in a certain room

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working through a problem, working with SQL Oracle. For some reason I am getting the result of 13 for instructors teaching that course when I should only be getting 1. There is only 1 Instructor that teaches only 3 or more students in that room.

**Question:**

Create a query to determine the number of instructors who have taught more than 3 students in a course section taught in Room L211.

**My Code:**

```
SELECT COUNT(Instructor_Id) AS NumberOfInstructors
FROM Section s, Enrollment e
WHERE s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id
  AND Location = 'L211'
HAVING COUNT(Student_Id) = 
(SELECT COUNT(Student_iD)
FROM Section s, Enrollment e
WHERE s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id
 AND Location = 'L211')
ORDER BY s.Course_No;
```

**My Results:**

```
NUMBEROFINSTRUCTORS   
-------------------   
13
```

**Expected Results:**

```
NUMBEROFINSTRUCTORS   
-------------------   
1
```

So I feel like Im kind of going in the right direction maybe not but I feel like it is adding all the instructors up that teach in that class. Ive messed around a lot with that code I've given so if anyone can point me in the right direction. I'm guessing I need to have a count for counting the students who have been in a class with that room number I think I've tried that and got a result of 4 so I'm not sure.

Any help would be great, also [here is the Schema](http://authors.phptr.com/rischert/documents/AppendixD.pdf).

DBMS: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: So, this is homework right?

Comment: It is a homework, but he did the right thing by "trying out first" and did his own research too.

Comment: Yeah but what about others that will just google it out and find out the answer. A quoted search for the question will return this as first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NumberOfInstructors
From (Select Instructor_Id
      FROM Section s
          join Enrollment e
                on e.Section_Id = s.Section_Id 
      WHERE s.Location = 'L211'
      Group By Instructor_Id
      HAVING COUNT(Student_Id) >= 3) Z
```

Comment: This one worked, I see what I did wrong also in this example the HAVING COUNT(Student_Id) >= 3) needs to just be > 3. It was showing the result being 4 instead of 1 because of that equal sign fyi

Answer (score 0):

I think you are needing a subquery here. In pseudo code, you are looking for a query like:

```
SELECT count(teachers)
FROM
  (SELECT count(students) FROM enrollment where location='L211') AS "numberofstudents"
WHERE numberofstudents > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I **did not** test the code, but it seems to me you are missing a condition. Your question requires you to find "Instructor that teaches only 3 or more students in that room", but you did not have any condition to check for student number > 3. Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Instructor_Id) AS NumberOfInstructors
FROM Section s, Enrollment e
WHERE s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id
AND Location = 'L211'
HAVING COUNT(Student_Id) = 
(SELECT COUNT(Student_iD)
FROM Section s, Enrollment e
WHERE s.Section_Id = e.Section_Id
AND Location = 'L211' AND COUNT(Student_Id) > 3)
ORDER BY s.Course_No;
```